# keycloak Spring Application behind reverse proxy - forwarding to http

Tags: spring, nginx, keycloak, reverse-proxy

we've set up keycloak, a spring service and nginx as https endpoint, all run in docker containers.

My issue is that the https request to nginx is redirected to http.

I call:
https://SERVER/myservice

it gets redirected to:

http://SERVER/sso/login but it should be `https`

I have set `PROXY_ADDRESS_FORWARDING` as well as `KEYCLOAK_FRONTEND_URL` but I'm not sure if in my example keycloak is contacted at all, or the redirect to `/sso/login` is done by the spring service?

***NGINX***

```
server {
    listen 443 ssl;
    server_name             _;

    ssl_certificate ...

    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_protocol_addr;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme; 
    proxy_set_header Host $host; 
    proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
    proxy_set_header Connection ‘upgrade’;

    location /myservice/ {
      proxy_set_header   Host $host;
      proxy_pass http://SERVER:8180/;
      proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
      proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
    }
```

Any help would be great! Thanks!

Comment: That looks like your spring generates wrong redirect url. Did you use ForwardedHeaderFilter?

Comment: No, nothing like this, just the default like in the example. Do you think we need a filter?

Comment: I guess you need `ForwardedHeaderFilter`, because Spring is not aware of SSL offloading on  the Nginx, so it generates http redirects.

Comment: We tried with ForwardHeaderFilter. Looks like it still forwards to http://.../sso/login then it would forward to https://.../sso/login. But I noticed that also my path /myservice/ get's lost, so it is contacting the wrong service anyway. Any idea how to preserve the path? Should it be covered by ForwardedHeaderFilter? How can I test it?